# loop through this Object that contain Array as values and combine all values, sort them, reindex and update values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have to loop through the object values and sort them in such a way that I remove number 1 & 2 (lets call it index) from Self and Spouse. Then reindex Child3 and Child4 to Child1 and Child2.

Though the Object got from API response looks like below it makes more sense to reindex them as I'll be displaying this information on the screen.

> Object looks like below: This is just a sample data. This object is
> dynamically created based on User household information

```
eligibilityMap: {
    "CHIP": [
        "CHILD3" // should be Child1
    ],
    "APTC/CSR": [
        "SELF1", //should be Self
        "SPOUSE2", //should be Spouse
        "CHILD4" //should be Child2
    ]
}
```

My question is how should I loop through this Object and just sort the child and reindex the same?

## Expected Result:

```
newMapping: {
    "CHIP": ["Child1"],
    "APTC/CSR": ["Self, Spouse and Child2"]
}
```

## CODE:

```
  var sortedMember = Object.keys(eligibilityMap).reduce((acc, key) => {
    //fetch the array for the given key
    var array = eligibilityMap[key];
    console.log('array', array);
    var sortedArray = array.sort( function (firstValue, secondValue) {
      if (firstValue.indexOf("SELF") >= 0) return -1;
      if (secondValue.indexOf("SELF") >= 0) return 1;

      if (firstValue.indexOf("SPOUSE") >= 0) return -1;
      if (secondValue.indexOf("SPOUSE") >= 0) return 1;

      return 0;
    });

    console.log("sortedArray", sortedArray)
    acc[key] = sortedArray;
    return acc;
  }, {})


  $scope.memberString = Object.keys(sortedMember).reduce(function (acc, key) {

    var array = sortedMember[key]

    var formattedString = array.reduce(function (memberAcc, member, index) {
      if (member.indexOf("SELF") >= 0) {
        return "Applicant"
      }

      if (member.indexOf("SPOUSE") >= 0) {
        var delimiter = index > 0  ? ", " : "";
        return memberAcc + delimiter + "Spouse"
      }

      if(index === 0) return member;

      var delimiter = index === array.length - 1 ? " and " : ", ";
      return memberAcc + delimiter + member //CHILD1
    }, "");

    console.log("STRING", key, formattedString)
   acc[key] = formattedString;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

## RESULT: (But still not what I wanted)

MEMBERS STRING {CHIP: "CHILD4", APTC/CSR: "Applicant, Spouse, CHILD3 and CHILD5"}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jered -- updated question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this approach. I've created a `dataMapper` to map the specific data with their new values.

```js
var obj = {
    "CHIP": [
        "CHILD3", // should be Child1
    ],
    "APTC/CSR": [
        "SELF1", //should be Self
        "SPOUSE2", //should be Spouse
        "CHILD4" //should be Child2
        
    ],
    "TEST": [
      "SELF1",
      "CHILD3"
    ]
};

// Code to support IE9

var i = 0;
var updatedObj = {};
var data = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  var values = obj[key];
  var memberArr = new Array();
  var dataObj = values.reduce(function(store, value) {
    var storeKey = value.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
    var number = Number(value.replace(/^\D+/g, ''));

    if(storeKey !== 'SELF' && storeKey !== 'SPOUSE') {
      var arr = new Array();
      for(i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        arr.push(storeKey);
        memberArr.push(storeKey);
      }
      store[storeKey] = arr;
    } else {
      var anotherArr = new Array(storeKey);
      memberArr.push(storeKey);
      store[storeKey] = anotherArr;
    }
    return store;
  }, {});
  memberArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  })
  var sortedMemberArr = memberArr.map(function(member, index) {
    return member+''+(index+1);
  })
  updatedObj[key] = sortedMemberArr;
})

console.log(updatedObj)



/*
// Code Using Modern Syntax

const data = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
  const memberCount = value.reduce((store, val) => {
    const key = val.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
    const number = +val.replace(/^\D+/g, '');

    if(!['SELF', 'SPOUSE'].includes(key)) {
      store[key] = Array(number).fill(key);  
    } else {
      store[key] = [key];
    }
    
    return store;
  }, {})
  
  const sortedMembers = Object.values(memberCount).flat().sort((a, b) => b - a);
  const sortedMembersWithNumber = sortedMembers.map((member, index) => `${member}${index+1}`)
  
  return [key, sortedMembersWithNumber]
})

const updatedObj = Object.fromEntries(data);

console.log(updatedObj)

*/
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode values. These values are dynamic. Not always eligibilityMap {} will have same information. It depend on what user enter. Some user may have spouse, may have child or not

Comment: Okey, What will happen if there is `chid10` and `test12`? What will be their updated value?

Comment: for example lets consider a household containing (self, and 3 children) then they are indexed as self1, child2, child3 and child4

Comment: lets consider a household containing (self, spouse and 1 child) then they are index as self1, spouse2, child3 and child4. Self will be always appended with index1. Other indexes may vary

Comment: so, for (self, 3 spouse, 3 child) the output will be (self1, spouse2, spouse3, spouse4, child5, child6, child7). Am i right?

Comment: yes. but as per my application, there can be only one self and one spouse

Comment: @dragonfly i've updated my answer. Would you please check now?

Comment: this code has to render on ie9 browser as well. I have taken your solution and modified it. But still running into issues. If you are interested, check https://jsfiddle.net/7bga2fzw/

Comment: @dragonfly would you please check now? I think this code should work in older browsers as well.